# MongoDB $exists count exceeds document count

Tags: mongodb

When I run this command:

```
db.stuff.find().count()
```

MongoDB returns `1415531`. When I run this command:

```
db.stuff.find({things:{$exists:true}}).count()
```

MongoDB returns `1415619`.

How is it possible for the second count to be greater than the first count??

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregate like this, this work for Mongodb 4.2

```
`db.stuff.aggregate([
 {$match: {things:{$exists:true} }},
 { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
 { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])`
```

Comment: Thanks, this may come in handy! But it doesn't really answer my question. Why is it possible for the `$exists` count to be higher than the number of documents?

Comment: can you  give your stuff collection schema ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot without exposing information that belongs to my client, but what is it you want to know about my schema? I will do my best to answer your question(s). :)